# How can i set a global variable value in one function and access it through another in codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, variables

I'm currently creating an app with Codeigniter and i came up with this issue (and it's not the first time to be honest).

What i want is to set a value in a global variable in function ***"foo()"*** and the access it through function ***"bar"*** (which is called through ajax call from client side).

In short, i want this variable to be full when the user has visited the page (sth like a session).

Here's an example code of my controller and what i'm trying to achieve:

```
class Groups extends CI_Controller{
  private $page_id;

  public function foo($slug = FALSE){
   $this->load->model('some_model');
   $info = $this->some_model->get_info($slug);
   $this->page_id = $info['page_id'];
  }

  public function bar(){
   $this->load->model('some_model');

   $info = $this->some_model->get_some_other_info($this->page_id);

   //Some code in here

  }
}
```

Any suggestions or best practices on achieve that?

I've tried searching the internet on that but i couldn't find something to start with. So if you have any suggestions on where to look at, feel free to do it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it right you will have 2 calls. One will be at page load where you want to store something and after that there will be an ajax call that will retrieve what you have stored. Because the 2 script loads are different you can only do it by storing the data to one of them: database/session/cookie/html session or localstorage.

Can't say anything about best practice because i dont know what you want to store and for how long so need a bit more info about your code (im guessing you want to store the "page_id"?).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want.

Let's see if i can make it more clear with a single list of steps:
1) User visits a page "e.g.: groups/edm"
2) Then in controller after getting the page's info, the page id should be stored in the variable.
3) Make an ajax call in the other function where i will take this variable and return the items assosiated with that page only..

I've thought of sessions but i don't know if this will affect speed, security etc.. of the page.

Comment: Well in that case i would suggest another way by storing the page_id in a hidden html input field at page generation. And when you want to ajax you just read that hidden inputs value and send it as post because if multiple tabs are open on the visitors page storing it in any other form would be much more complicated because one would overwrite the other value like in a session. Neither of them will affect speed and security much just be sure to filter/sanitize the page_id before inserting it to a query.

Comment: Ok got it! I wanted to prevent a user to edit the field value, but since i will do a server side check for permissions i think it is not a bad practice! 

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: If you want to be 100% secure and don't show the page_id than just send the 'slug' to the ajax and do another query where you just fetch the page_id. Won't take longer than 0.001 seconds.

Comment: Based on @Mikeyhun's approach there's another option for (i think) bigger safety. 
Instead of "slug" you can create an "identifier" field with a random alphanumeric string in it, and then create a function in order to get the page_id based on this identifier.

Comment: You are now just over complicating the things and trying to do the same stuff. Just filter/sanitize the "slug" and there won't be any problems ;)